# Open a dialog in main

Tags: python, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

I want to open a dialog file into the main of the program. I have not error but I my dialog no appear. I think I have to say to "QQmlApplicationEngine" who is the parent and I put the parent but nothing append.

engine = QQmlApplicationEngine(app)      <- app : it is like that for declare who is the parent ?

main.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
try:    
    from PyQt5.QtCore import (
        pyqtProperty, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot,
        QAbstractListModel, QModelIndex, QObject, Qt, QTimer, QVariant, QMetaObject,
    )
    from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication
    from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine
    from PyQt5.QtQuick import QQuickView

    import sys

except ImportError as e:
    raise ImportError(e)

class openDialog(object):

    def __init__(self, parent, app):

        engine = QQmlApplicationEngine(app)
        engine.load('dialog.qml')               

        ''' '''
        if not engine.rootObjects():
            sys.exit(app.exec_())

        win = engine.rootObjects()[0]
        ctx = engine.rootContext()

        #ctx.findChild(QObject, "dialog1").setProperty("visible", 1)    
        #win.findChild(QObject, "lbl1").setProperty("text", "toto")     
        #win.findChild(QObject, "dialog1").setProperty("visible", 1)        

        print('dialog')


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
    context = engine.rootContext()

    engine.load("main.qml")

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    win = engine.rootObjects()[0]

    openDialog(win, app)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.13
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    title: qsTr("WoodMan Training")
    width: 600
    height: 400
    visible: true
}
```

dialog.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.13
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.1

Dialog {
    anchors.centerIn: parent

    id: msgDialog
    objectName: "dialog1"
    title: "Title"
    modal: true
    visible:true
    standardButtons: Dialog.Ok

    onAccepted: console.log("Ok clicked")
    onRejected: console.log("Cancel clicked")

    Label {
        objectName: "lbl1"
        text: "un texte"
    }           
}
```

Comment: I don't know python at all, but ... do you recreate the `QQmlApplicationEngine` inside openDialog? That's totally wrong, should be only one instance of that. Another error - you should not access/modify QML items from C++ (or in your case from python) until there is no special need. Open the dialog from inside QML. Another mistake - the `visible` should be false, otherwise the dialog will be shown on startup.

Comment: Why do you want the Dialog to be opened from Python? I think you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Good practices indicate that the GUI must be implemented in QML.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. In fact I thought a dialog window was only a window but already pre-configure ... error on my part. I went to do some research, with your advice, and I saw that it is better to use javascript to manage that. And it works very well. Thank you.